# Display new line depending on users input of terms per line

Tags: c++

This program outputs terms in a Jugglers Series based on user input of first term, number of terms to calculate and terms per line

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

//prototype 
int ValidateInput (string Prompt);


int main() 
{
    //local variables
    long long int firstTerm;
    int termsToCalc;
    int termsPerLine;
    int count;


    //tells user what program does
    cout << "Program will determine the terms in a Juggler Series" << endl << endl;

    //calls user function to read in the frist term
    firstTerm = ValidateInput ("Enter the first term: ");
    cout << endl;

    //calls user function to read in the number of terms to calculate (after the first)
    termsToCalc = ValidateInput ("Enter the number of terms to calculate (after the first): ");
    cout << endl;

    //calls user function to read in the number of terms to display per line 
    termsPerLine = ValidateInput ("Enter the terms to display per line: ");
    cout << endl;

    cout << "First " << termsToCalc << " terms of Juggler series starting with " << firstTerm << endl << endl;

    count = 1;

    do
    {   
        if ((count % termsPerLine) == 0)
        {
            cout << "\n";
        }

        //the term is even take it to the power of 1/2 and increase the count 1
        if (firstTerm % 2 == 0 )
        {
            firstTerm = pow(firstTerm , 0.5);
            cout << setw(16) << firstTerm << endl;
            count++;
        }
        //the term is odd take it to the power of 3/2, and increase the count 1
        else
        {           
            firstTerm = pow(firstTerm, 1.5);
            cout << setw(16) << firstTerm << endl;
            count++;
        }
    }
    //continue looping until the terms to calculate is no longer less than or 
    // equal to the count
    while (count <= termsToCalc);


    return 0;
}



int ValidateInput (string Prompt)
{
    //local variable
    int number;

    //prompts user for first term, and reads in number
    cout << Prompt;
    cin >> number;

    //user input must be positive, a while loop will check user input and 
    //continue to check until the term is positive.
    while (number <=0)
    {
        cout << "Error - Enter a positive number" << endl;
        cin >> number;
    }

    //returns number to main function
    return number;

}
```

This is the current printout
[image: Current print out]

This is how I would like it to look
[image: but I want it to print like this]

I can not figure out how to edit the output statement to make this display correctly

---

After removing the endls and moving the new line statement to the end I now get the correct print out but with an extra term

[image: extra term]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, remove the `endl`s from these:

```
cout << setw(16) << firstTerm << endl; // ->  cout << setw(16) << firstTerm;
```

And perhaps move this part:

```
 if ((count % termsPerLine) == 0)
 {
        cout << "\n";
 }
```

to the end of the loop. So it becomes:

```
 count = 0;

    do {
        if (firstTerm % 2 == 0 ) { 
            firstTerm = pow(firstTerm , 0.5);
            cout << setw(16) << firstTerm;
        } else {    
            firstTerm = pow(firstTerm, 1.5);
            cout << setw(16) << firstTerm;
        }

        if ( (count + 1) % termsPerLine == 0) {
            cout << "\n";
        }

        count++;

    } while (count < termsToCalc);
```

Comment: have to use a do while loop. I can add more to the post now that I have removed the endls, now the format is correct but the count is screwing up the lines

Comment: figured out the extra term! while (count <= termsToCalc) needed to be just <....Thanks for your help!